# Does $f'(x)\equiv\dfrac{1}{x^2+f^2(x)}$ for $x\geqslant 1$ and $f(1)=1$ imply $f(+\infty)$ exists?

Tags: calculus

I can see $f'(+\infty)=0$ from the identity, then it seems to suggest that $f(+\infty)=L<+\infty$, however I can not give a proof.

Comment: It looks like a difficult(?) differential equation.  Have you tried to solve it?

Comment: @herbsteinberg I can't think about how to solve it because it's non-linear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that from the derivative we can conclude that $f(x)\geq 1$ for $x\geq 1$ whence
$$
0\leq f'(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+f^2(x)}\leq \frac{1}{1+x^2}
$$
and 
$$
f(x)=f(1)+\int_{1}^xf'(t)\, dt
$$
from which the result follows.

Comment: I see, then $f(x)\leqslant 1+\arctan{x}-\dfrac{\pi}{4}$, I have just $f(+\infty)\leqslant 1+\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ by letting $x\to\infty$. What about then?

Comment: Since $f$ is increasing on $[1, \infty)$, it follows that $\sup_{x\geq 1} f(x)=\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)\leq 1+\pi/4<\infty$ as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $f(x) = f(1) +\int_1^x f'(t)\,dt.$ Show $\int_1^\infty f'(t)\,dt$ converges.